# Fluent Nhibernate and MySql, problems with dialect

Tags: mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have question about fluent nhibernate and mysql. I'm doing this:

```
Fluently.Configure()    
.Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ShowSql())    
.Mappings(m =>        
m.FluentMappings        
.AddFromAssemblyOf<ShopperMapping>())    
.BuildConfiguration();SchemaExport 
exp = new SchemaExport(cfg);
exp.Execute(true, false, false, true);
```

But when doing this I get failures like "Dialect does not support DbType.Uint32" and the likes. I get the same for mapped properties that are of type Uint64 (ulong). Why does this happen? Does anyone know? Do I need to map in some other way? Like explicitly saying which access strategy to use or something like that?

Regards, Jörgen

Answer (score 3):

NHibernate does not support unsigned integer types. The full list of basic types implemented by NHibernate can be found [in the documentation](https://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/1.2/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-types-basictypes).

I don't know of any "official word" as to why they are not, but if I had to guess it's that [some* major database engines](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/default.aspx) for whatever reason [do not support unsigned integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx).

**for appropriately small values of "some"*